# Why must I download socket.io.js from that server?

Tags: socket.io

I noticed that the recommended way is to download the client js from the server:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

Is this because it is dynamically generated? Can I write the `script` to make it to download from a static source?

---

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

This makes the `app` accept requests in the `/socket.io` path. What exactly happens here, since it accepts WS, comet and even requests for the client js file?

Comment: I forgot about advantages of loading client js from Socket.IO server. Please take a look at the update of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431352/2600208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this because it is dynamically generated?

No, there is a `socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js` file, which is served by Socket.IO as a static content.

> Can I write the script to make it to download from a static source?

Yes, of course. Moreover [there is a Socket.IO CDN](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#cdn-delivery) and you can include `socket.io.js` with this URL: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js . Doing this way you will get "maximum level of gzip compression and proper support for caching".

> What exactly happens here, since it accepts WS, comet and even requests for the client js file?

Unfortunatelly I don't know :) The answer requires a good knowledge of Socket.IO architecture. If you have strong desire and free time you can learn Socket.IO source code to understand how it works inside. It would be a very good experience :)

I hope my answer helps you. Good luck

**Update:**

Among advantages of loading client library from Socket.IO server there is a fact that you don't have to worry about versions conflict -- when upgrading Socket.IO on the server you will get the same version of Socket.IO client lib.